# Is there a way to limit legends on a horizontal layout on specific amount of rows during export?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts latest version and trying to export a chart on a png and trying to see if there is a way to limit the number of rows shown on the exported png using the horizontal layout up to 2 rows if the legends are breaking into more than 2 rows.

A working export example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/siluok3/085gzjtn/7/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    style: {
      fontFamily: '"Arial", sans-serif',
      color: '#7b797a',
      'z-index': 'inherit'
    },
    resetZoomButton: {
      theme: {
        fill: '#5cb85c',
        stroke: '#4cae4c',
        style: {
          color: '#fff',
          fontSize: '15px'
        },
        r: 3,
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: '#449d44',
            stroke: '#398439'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Data labels only visible on export'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
    style: {
      display: "none"
    }
  },

  legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 32,
    itemStyle: {
      color: '#7b797a',
      fontWeight: "normal"
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
      color: '#7b797a'
    }
  },

  navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
      theme: {
        'stroke-width': 0,
        r: 0,
        fill: null,
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: null
          },
          select: {
            stroke: null,
            fill: null
          }
        }
      }
    },
    menuItemHoverStyle: {
      background: '#008add'
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      rotation: 270
    },
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mayfsdfdsfdsf', 'Junfdfsd', 'Julfsdfsdfds', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    data: [6, 4, 2],
    name: 'Firfdsfdsst'
  }, {
    data: [7, 3, 2],
    name: 'Secfsdfdsdfond'
  }, {
    data: [9, 4, 8],
    name: 'Third'
  }, {
    data: [1, 2, 6],
    name: 'Fourth'
  }, {
    data: [4, 6, 4],
    name: 'Fifdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfth'
  }, {
    data: [1, 2, 7],
    name: 'Sixth'
  }, {
    data: [4, 2, 5],
    name: 'Sevefdsfdsfdsfsdnth'
  }, {
    data: [8, 3, 2],
    name: 'Efdsfdsfdsfdsighth'
  }, {
    data: [4, 5, 6],
    name: 'Nifdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfnth'
  }, {
    data: [4, 2, 5],
    name: 'Sevefdsfdsfdsfsdnth'
  }, {
    data: [8, 3, 2],
    name: 'Efdsfdsfdsfdsighth'
  }, {
    data: [4, 5, 6],
    name: 'Nifdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfnth'
  }],

  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      legend: {
        title: {
          text: '',
        },
        itemHiddenStyle: {
          display: 'none',
        },
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        itemDistance: 10,
        y: 0,
        itemMarginTop: 5,
        itemStyle: {
          fontSize: '10px',
        },
        symbolPadding: 2,
        alignColumns: false,
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
      },
      navigator: {
        enabled: false
      },
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
      },
    }
  }

});

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

As you can see the legends break into a 3rd row if they are more or larger. Is there an intuitive way to find a workaround?

Comment: Hi @Kiriakos Papachristou, How would you like to limit the rows? Do you want to reduce the items size or their amount?

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek both implementations should be fine as soon as reducing the item's size doesn't hide the legend's text and show only the legend's symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itemWidth` property to limit the width of the item and, as a result, the number of rows. Unfortunately for now there is no built-in solution for dynamically adjusting the number of rows in the legend.

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        legend: {
            itemWidth: 90,
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gtjewc1v/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemWidth

Comment: Thanks, indeed I'll have either use some existing options from the Highchart's API or just create an event to calculate some widths and kinda get the outcome I want to.